# duplicate configurable products issue

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, backend

I'm using magento 2.3.3 and I need to duplicate some configurable products.

Every products has some sizes and color, each color has a custom image. When I duplicate a configurable product I see that the virtual products associated are not duplicated (the virutal skus doesn't change).

There is a way to duplicate a configurable product and duplicate it's virutal products?
If it's not possible, how can I erase all confiugrations in the new duplicated product?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to implement this module : https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-fix-duplicate ?

Comment: Hi @MBK1People, nope but my issue is on configurable virtual's product not on related (I don't set any related product)